# How to configure beforeShowForm with lib.web.mvc to show non editable columns in add form

Tags: jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

Some of my columns are not editable but I want all of the columns to display in the add form.

I was thinking that I can use the "beforeShowForm" event and call a javascript function that will dynamically change the column attribute back to editable so they will show up in the add form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach for this is to make fields generally editable and hide them in edit dialog.

You can hide/show fields by looking for table rows which ids are being built like this:

```
tr_ColumnName
```

So in case you would have UserName column the id would be like this:

```
tr_UserName
```

Assuming you are using jQuery, you can wire-up this to your Lib.Web.Mvc configuration like this:

```
.Navigator(new Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridNavigatorOptions() { ... },
    editActionOptions: new Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridNavigatorEditActionOptions()
    {
        ...
        BeforeShowForm : "function(form) { $('#tr_UserName', form).hide(); }"
    },
    addActionOptions: new Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridNavigatorEditActionOptions()
    {
        ...
        BeforeShowForm : "function(form) { $('#tr_UserName', form).show(); }"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured how to use the event **beforeShowForm**.

Note: I have a using statement at the top of the view, so do not need to use the full namespace

```
@using Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid
```

Here is an example within the Navigator form:

```
.Navigator(new JqGrid.JqGridNavigatorOptions() 
{ Add = true, Edit = false, Delete = false, Search = false }, 
null, 
addActionOptions: new JqGridNavigatorEditActionOptions()
    {
        Url = Url.Action("Add"),
        BeforeShowForm = "function () {$('#bob').jqGrid('setColProp', 
        'Place', {editable:true})
    })
```